# Can I upload an entire folder using FTP?

Tags: ftp

I need to upload a full folder using FTP.  Is there is any option for transferring a folder and all of its contents at once?

Answer (score 32):

You can use ncftpput. Do the following:

1. Install ncftp:

   ```
   yum install ncftp
   ```

yum is lowercase.

Alternatively:

```
    apt-get install ncftp
```

2. Execute the following command:

```
    ncftpput -R -v -u "ftp-username" ftp.website.com ftp-upload-path local-path/*
```

Comment: The Yum should be changed to yum - as it is case-sensitive.

Comment: Here are all CLI options for ncftpput: http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html

Comment: What I like about this solution: automatable!

Comment: Great!  use the -p "passwd" then I can write it in bash script and run auto.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using a standard command-line ftp client, the `MPUT` command will allow you to transfer all files matching a (shell glob-style) pattern, so `MPUT *` will send all files in the current directory.  There is also `MGET` to retrieve files matching a pattern.

By default, both `MPUT` and `MGET` will prompt for whether to transfer each file before doing so.  You'd probably want to turn off prompting with the "PROMPT" command (no argument; it's a toggle).

Comment: This question originally came from stackoverflow, so I feel that it should be the accepted answer. Though the original asker seems to have vanished so isn't going to accept one....

Comment: Warning: the FTP command line client that comes with Windows doesn't support passive mode so using this technique may waste your time.  It did in my case since I needed to upload files and was using the Windows command line w/ natively installed tooling.

Comment: It will transfer all the plain files in the current directory but it will not transfer recursively any directories that are present. It will just ignore them silently

Answer (score 8):

Use an FTP client such as LeechFTP or FileZilla or something similar. Many people swear by CuteFTP, but it's shareware last I checked. All support transferring a whole folder including directory structure.

Comment: +1 for FileZilla: http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

Answer (score 5):

1. have the user/client zip the folder
2. upload the zip file
3. [unzip the folder server side](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx).

Comment: note: my answer was posted at StackOverflow. That's why it references a "coding" solution.

Answer (score 3):

A simple tutorial for other Windows newbies like me who wind up here:

The easiest way to upload an entire folder (with all subfolders and files in them) is:

1. Download [NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) (it's free, but you can donate) [from this link](http://www.ncftp.com/download/).
2. Choose **NcFTP Client 3.2.5 for Microsoft Windows** from the list.
3. Install it.
4. When done, a small CMD window with a cherries icon will pop-up. You don't need it.
5. Just open a standard CMD window and type:

   ```
   ncftpput -u *yourUserNameHere* -p *yourUserPasswordHere* -R *www.yourWebsite.com* /
                    _C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere\\*_
   ```

   (as one line).

Note that:

- `-R`  is a flag for "recursive"; it makes the command copy all subfolders recursively
- `/` (slash) is your website's root directory
- `C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere\*` selects everything inside *`C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere`*

Comment: looks nice, but the server banned my IP saying i made 800 connections in short interval. no way to reduce number of connections. ANOTHER problem is that i do not know how to skip uploading if destination file exist already.

Answer (score 3):

I'll offer an answer which - though it is pure brute force and not elegant in the slightest - was the only thing that worked for me on the command line. I created a list of the files, and put them into a script:

generate your list of files:

```
find my-dir -exec echo "put /Users/username/"{} {}  \;
```

copy and paste them into the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname="my-ftp-host"
username="username"
password="password"
ftp -in $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password

binary
cd 123456
{COPY THE LIST HERE}
quit
EOF
```

Comment: by bash u mean this only works in unix?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252000/upload-a-folder-by-ftp).

You can also [programmatically create a folder on the server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.makedirectory.aspx), and then upload all files to that new folder.

Comment: The linked SO question has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla is great for this.  If you don't want to download/install anything, this can be done with Internet Explorer.  Go into the advanced options, and select `Enable FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)`.  Then you can point an explorer window at your FTP server and drag-and-drop files and folders between explorer windows.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a plug-in called [FireFtp](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) that is a nice ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

The target dir is a zip file. You can copy the full zip file into the ftp server using below code.

```
//Taking source and target directory path
string sourceDir = FilePath + "Files\\" + dsCustomer.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "\\ConfigurationFile\\" + dsSystems.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() + "\\XmlFile";

string targetDir = FilePath + "Files\\Customers\\" + CustomerName + "\\" + SystemName + "\\";                                                                                       
foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
{
    //Taking file name which is going to copy from the sourcefile                                              
    string result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(srcPath);

    //If that filename exists in the target path
    if (File.Exists(targetDir + result))
    {
        //Copy file with a different name(appending "Con_" infront of the original filename)
        System.IO.File.Copy(srcPath, targetDir + "Con_" + result);
    }
    //If not existing filename
    else
    {
        //Just copy. Replace bit is false here. So there is no overwiting.
        File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourceDir, targetDir), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but your program doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is variation of @dgig 's answer.

You can list all the files and save them (including put command) into a file:

```
find my-dir -exec echo "put /Users/username/"{} {} > list.txt \;
```

and then use sftp to process the file:

```
sftp -C -b sftpbatchfile.txt name@server
```

`-C` is for compression, `-b` is for batch file

Comment: This does not use FTP as asked. The `sftp` program uses the SFTP protocol which is a different protocol although it has some letters in common. And you didn't edit the `enter code here` leftover.